# Xcode 11 compatibility with .net MAUI app

Tags: xcode, maui, visual-studio-2022

Im building a .NET MAUI app on my windows. Works fine for Android. But shows multiple errors as soon as i Build for iOS. I paired with mac which has xcode 11 installed and I do get warning that `The Xcode version installed on the Mac (11.0) is not compatible with this version of Visual Studio`.

Can anyone confirm if MAUI does work with Xcode older versions installed on MAC? Or only later versions are compatible?

**Applications:**

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.7.4

Xcode 11 on MAC 10.15

Comment: What version of VS and XCode do you have, and please be SPECIFIC!

Comment: @FreakyAli updated my questions. I m running VS 2022 and Xcode 11

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms)

> iOS 11 or higher, using the latest release of Xcode.

Generally, Apple requires you to use the next to latest or latest version of Xcode and iOS to deploy to the App Store

Comment: for now, I just want to run app in iOS simulator on VS2022. but the app shows error for iOS. Im yet to deploy on app store

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click App Project and check the following settings:

[image]

[image]

Hope this already helps...

Comment: where does it specify xcode version?

Comment: In it is not specified which XCode to use in VS. VS just will send a request to build to the Mac. Therefore I would assume it is just important which target version to support. I also use an older Version of XCode (14.3), but not as old as yours. I would assume with these settings it should work. Did you check the settings and it did not?

Comment: yes i tried these settings and it didnt work.

Comment: Do you try from PC to Mac or Mac to Mac? I am not sure if also a VS or .NET Installation is needed on the Mac, as I also have it installed on my Mac, too and connect PC to Mac. Just had something in mind from when I started, that I read a tip to have both installations of VS the same on PC and Mac. So, if you have the capacity on your Mac it could be worth a try to install the same version of VS/.NET on PC and Mac. Other than that, I am out :(